# Help with understanding Cholesky Factorization

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello I need some help with cholesky factorization
I have the following matrix 
$ \begin{bmatrix}
4 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 5 & 2 \\
0 & 2 & 5 
\end{bmatrix}  $

I've calculated L to be $ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  $

But when I computer $L*L^{t}$ I don't get back my original matrix
 I have a 1 in $a_{11}$ when it should be a 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an algorithm that is probably worth learning. The simple result can be modified quickly to give a Cholesky factorization:

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 4 \\ 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix} 
= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
4 & 2 & 0 \\ 
2 & 5 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 5 \\ 
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

modify:
$$ (2Q)^T (D/4) (2Q) = H  $$

---

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \begin{pmatrix} 
4 & 2 & 0 \\ 
2 & 5 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 5 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
\begin{gather}
D_0 = H, \qquad
E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j, \qquad
P_{j-1} E_j = P_j \\
E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j, \qquad
P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I, \qquad
P_j^T H P_j = D_j, \qquad
Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H.
\end{gather}
$$ H =
\begin{pmatrix} 
4 & 2 & 0 \\ 
2 & 5 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 5 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

---

$$ E_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}, \qquad
Q_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}, \qquad
D_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 4 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 5 \\ 
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

---

$$ E_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$  P_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}, \qquad
Q_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}, \qquad
D_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 4 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

---

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
4 & 2 & 0 \\ 
2 & 5 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 5 \\ 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 4 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 4 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 
4 & 2 & 0 \\ 
2 & 5 & 2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 5 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$